# How do I get started with ATWINC-IC from Microchip?

Tags: avr, microchip, wifi, atmel-studio

I want to get started with ATWINC-IC from Microchip. It's a WiFi IC that I'm going to implement onto a PCB.

I have installed Microchip Studio and now I'm looking for how to start a project with that IC. I assume that with ATWINC-IC, I can program the IC with I2C or UART.

[image]

So to begin with, I need to know which programmer I should use for this ATWINC-IC and what software I should use and how do I create a first time hello world project to deploy onto that WiFi-chip e.g a web page or blink an LED.

https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/ATWINC1500-IC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ATWINC1500 is a network controller; it does not function standalone, and must be driven by another microcontroller using the SPI interface (clock, chip select, data in, data out), and a few other lines (wake, enable, reset and interrupt).

The device is pre-programmed, so you don't initially need a programmer; you'll be writing code for the microcontroller that is driving the device. Here is an example [using RP2040 with ATWINC1500](https://iosoft.blog/winc_wifi/)

Comment: I understand! Sounds nice to hear that this WiFi controller is pre-programmed and does not require any more programming. All I need to do is to have SPI connection to a host MCU. Thank you. Thinks information was very helpful.

Comment: One question more. The ATWINC1500-IC...is that pre-programmed as well? The naked IC-chip.

Comment: I don't know, you'll have to ask on the Microchip forum, but if you are a newcomer to this device, I'd strongly suggest starting with a module, to avoid tricky microwave design.

Comment: Thank you. I will use WF200 instead. Seems to be suitable for STM32.

Answer (score 1):

The link you posted has a long list of documentation including a programming guide, I would start there.